# Can I use django.contrib.gis on GAE?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, gis

Can I use GeoDjango with GAE / BigTable?

Comment: What makes you think you might not be able to? Have you tried it and encountered errors?  If so, what errors?  Have you heard reports of errors? If so, what errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can't use Django models on App Engine, and therefore, can't use anything else that uses them, such as django.contrib.gis.

Comment: Thanks, more on this can be found here: http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine

Comment: OBSOLETE!! 1) Django is now supported with `cloud SQL` see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934914/why-use-django-on-google-app-engine/28627569#28627569 and 2) there is option to get geo support: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11268661/953553

Answer (score 5):

Another limitation is that the GEOS and GDAL libs aren't available on App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in `geohash`: read a [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525747/how-to-best-design-a-date-geographic-proximity-query-on-gae/2537798#2537798).