# Does google app engine with mysql (Cloud SQL) support GIS?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, geodjango, google-cloud-sql

I have tried to find some documentation on this on the app engine and cloud sql sites, but can't find anything referring to it either way. I know that you can perform GIS queries on their custom sql option, and I know mysql supports GIS out of the box, but I also know it requires some C libraries which there is limited support for.

More particularly I am interested to know if geo-django using mysql supports gis using an app engine/cloud sql combination. (Or maybe if their custom offering supports geodjango?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GeoDjango with Cloud SQL is not supported. GeoDjango depends on several libraries that are not available in app engine. Any app with a dependency on `django.contrib.gis.db.models` throws a whitelist error in the app engine development server. Presumably, an equivalent error would be encountered on a live app engine instance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Cloud SQL does support [Spatial Queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gis-introduction.html).  I don't know if it works with geodjango, but I don't see why it wouldn't.

Keep in mind that Mysql geospatial queries require myisam tables.  Myisam tables can get corrupted much more easily than innodb tables, so you should be very careful about using them.  Specifically, if your data changes frequently, you should expect to have to restore from backup on occasion.  In that case, consider using the [Search API for geospatial queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/geopointclass) instead.  If the data changes infrequently (e.g. a physical store locator), the myisam tables will probably work just fine.

Comment: For my use case, the data is either initially set and then ignored, or changes frequently and is disposable, so I don't expect any problems, but thanks for the pointer - I will consider while working on future projects.

Comment: I also don't know that simply having the support in mysql means it is available in app engine. MySQL requires several additional libraries (libcgeos + others) to support spatial queries.

Comment: @CoatedMoose What was your final setup for `Geodjango` on `Google App Engine` and how sucesfully you were with using it?

Comment: @andi my answer explains the issues encountered. Ultimately, the project was backburnered and later canned entirely, so no further attempts to make the project app engine compatible were made. I have not investigated either Cloud SQL or GeoDjango recently, so the situation may have changed.

Comment: MySQL innodb supports spatial queries since version 5.7